# Is it possible to mock all the objects around an eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've been trying for a while now to do something a bit strange...

I need to invoke some code that gets executed by a eclipse rcp wizard window from outside the rcp environment.

Basically some third party team has built an installer using the eclipse rcp framework and one of the functionalities of this installer is to export some data.

I need to perform that same data export programmatically but from outside this whole rcp scope. (basically from ant).

The issues I seem to be facing are connected to not having the org.osgi.framework.BundleContext objects populated.

Any idea how I can mock them?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... import org.springframework.osgi.mock;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: yeah it does! I was asking how could I mock the BundleContext objects and I've found that there is a spring module with that in mind. I'm not explaining all the boiler plate code or work behind it but face it if the person interested is reading this question then it probably has a good idea how to deal with that response.